# How do I create a template Junit 5 test in a library that others can just reference with test data?

Tags: junit5

I want to create a Test template of some sort that others can just provide a simple set of data to and run through a complex set of tests.

In my case I want to test data migrations in a DB and want to set up how to test and the user of my test should just add Data of a certain type to. My thoughts so far are like this:

I have an object that contains the data in both the old and the new format (and the class of the migration to apply to it). This is the Parameter that the user of my library should provide. I then have a lib containing all the code for how to test this right and what tests to run.

Basically, I want the User to create a method that provides the data, not the test code.

I have seen a solution where you extend the class containing all the test cases and only override the method they use as @MethodSource, but somehow this feels liek it is not the best solution, so I am looking for other suggestions that somehow look "cleaner".

Answer (score 0):

One option is to look into [JUnit5 Dynamic Tests](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dynamic-tests), as that favours composition over inheritance.

You can have one class that generates a test suite, like

```java
public final class SharedTest {
  public static Collection<DynamicTest> getTestSuite(Bridge bridge) {
    List<DynamicTest> tests = new ArrayList<>();
    tests.add(
        dynamicTest(
            "canPerformAction",
            () -> {
              bridge.performAction();
              assertTrue(bridge.wasSuccess());
            }));
    // etc...
    return tests;
  }
}
```

The `Bridge` is an interface that decouples the shared test suite from the concrete target test suite.

To hook this into the target tests, you'd do

```java
class MyTest {
  @TestFactory
  Collection<DynamicTest> getTestSuite() {
    return SharedTest.getTestSuite(new Bridge() {
      @Override
      public void performAction() {
        // concrete implementation
      }

      // etc...
    });
}
```